# Shopify Trying to update a customer

Tags: javascript, shopify, updates, liquid

I'm trying to create a view where my customer can update his personal info (like First Name, Last Name, email, ect) using Liquid/JS, but I have failed epicly.

The nearest point that I have reached is [this post](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/t/allowing-a-customer-to-edit-their-profile-and-metadata-186665) where they use a form and some AJAX to update but I'm getting code 500. This is the code that I'm using (based on that).

```
     <form action="/a/custmeta" method="POST" id="custmeta">  
   <input type="text" name="customer[id]" value="{{ customer.id }}" />
   <input type="text" name="customer[first_name]" value="{{ customer.first_name }}" placeholder="namespace1.key1" />
   <input type="text" name="customer[last_name]" value="{{ customer.last_name }}" placeholder="namespace2.key2" />
   <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <script>

    $('form#custmeta').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: '/admin/customers/#{{ customer.id }}.json',
        success: function (data) {
          var formValid = (data.status === 'OK');
          if (formValid) {
            var msgs = '';
            for (var i=0;i<data.messages.length;i++) {
              msgs += '-- ' + data.messages[i] + '\n';
            }
            if (msgs > '') {
              alert('SUCCESS WITH MESSAGES:\n\n' + msgs);
            }
            else {
              alert('SUCCESS!');
            }
          }
          else {
              alert('Status: ' + data.status + '\nMessage: ' + data.message);
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('AJAX or Server 500 error occurred');
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  </script>
```

found this [other post](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#update) where you could do it using the API but dont know how to use it.

Any help?

Comment: The first link you provided explicitly mentions usage of multiple apps. In order to use API (as in second link) you still need to use an app.

Comment: why the `#` in this line?
    `url: '/admin/customers/#{{ customer.id }}.json'`

Comment: Also, are you sure it's a 500 level error? Because your error callback would get called if it's a 400 level error, too. And the typo with the `#` might be causing a 404